# Скрыть <select> если у него один <option>

Tags: javascript, html, select, cssselect

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста, необходима простая функция js.
Задача в следующем, к примеру есть html код:

```
<select class="form-select">
    <option value="All"></option>
</select> 
<select class="form-select">
    <option value="All"></option>
    <option value="25"></option>
</select>
```

Необходимо сделать, чтобы если в select заключен только один option, то селекту присваивалось css значение - display:none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $('.form-select').each(function(){
      if($(this).find('option').length<2){
        $(this).hide()
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select"> 
  <option value="All"></option> 
</select> 
<select class="form-select"> 
  <option value="All"></option> 
  <option value="25"></option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Взял на себя смелость отредактировать форматирование. Если вы с этим несогласны, откатите ваш ответ к предыдущей версии.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $selects = $('.form-select');
for(var i = 0 ; i < $selects.length; i++){
   if($selects[i].children().lenght == 1){
      $selects[i].css('display', 'none');
   }
}
```

Добавлю что прописывать `display: none` лучше через `css` класс

Comment: Обращаться к конкретному элементу jQuery-коллекции лучше через `.eq(i)`, для скрытия существует метод `.hide()`, саму итерацию обычно делают через `.each(function () {})`.