# Скрыть один input, если в дргом значение 0

Tags: javascript, html, select, cssselect

Доброго времени суток всем! Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно скрыть один input, если в другом значение будет 0. То есть:

```
 <div><span class="label">123</span><input type="text" name="fld1"  value="0"></div>
```

Тогда другой в это время будет скрыт. Но если человек меняет значение на другое, то открывается другой input ля ввода.
Пробовал делать по этому ответу данному [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423210/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-select-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-option), но не увенчалось успехом(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С трудом понял набор слов, но думаю суть скрипта ясна:

> Как можно скрыть один input, если в другом значение будет 0, тогда другой в это время будет скрыт. Но если человек меняет значение на другое, то открывается другой input для ввода.

http://jsfiddle.net/bonmzw4u/

```js
if(!parseInt($('#one').val())) {
 $('#two').hide();    
}

$('#one').on('input', function() {
 ((!parseInt($('#one').val())) ? $('#two').hide() : $('#two').show());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="one" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="two" />
```

Comment: Да) Прошу прощения за "набор слов") Большое спасибо!